# How to start coding for posterior inference

Tags: bayesian, inference, posterior

I am trying to implement the model given in http://proceedings.mlr.press/v84/andersen18a/andersen18a.pdf where they have used mean-field variational inference for posterior inference, but I want to use MCMC for inference. I am new to Bayesian statistics and I am currently facing challenges in implementation. I am free to use any language. Is there any good source which I can use as a reference to start. I would be really grateful if anyone could provide pseudo code or something which I can use as a starting point. How do one infer about $\beta$ and $K$. Below is their model- 
\begin{align}
\Lambda_t^{n} = \frac{1}{\beta} \mathbf{I} + \Sigma_{k=1}^K \alpha_{k,t}^nv_kv_k^T
\end{align}
where $\mathbf{\alpha}_k^n \sim GP(m_k^n,C_k^n)$, GP is the Gaussian process, $v_k$ has horseshoe prior, $\Lambda_t^n$ is a covariance matrix and we have a p dimensional time series data of length T, so here we are trying to estimate dynamic covariance matrices.